# Why Firefox doesn't zoom page elements other than text?

Tags: firefox, zoom

On this Dilbert strip I've noticed that if with my Firefox 22 I increase the zoom level with `Ctrl`+`+`, most of the text grows but the image of the comic strip does not. First I thought it's some trick at Dilbert's but tried that on other pages it is the same

Historically I were able to zoom the whole page. Why am I not now? Is this a change in firefox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mozilla support site [explains](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/font-size-and-zoom-increase-size-of-web-pages?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Page+Zoom#w_how-do-i-switch-to-text-zoom) that there is `page zoom` and `text zoom` and that while the default is page zoom, you can also *switch* to `text zoom`.

> To switch to Text Zoom:
>
> 1. Press the Alt key to temporarily bring up the traditional Firefox menus. At the top of the Firefox window, click the View menu, then go
>      to Zoom.
> 2. Select Zoom Text Only, which will make the controls only apply to text, not images.

What happened is that I somehow accidentally enabled the use text zoom only.

Untick it, and there I have 'normal' zoom again.